# Map is not rendering in View using React-Native-Maps npm package with long and lat

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

I have a react native project I am building. I am trying to integrating `react-native-maps`. I currently have a `View` that is `400px X 400px` that I want to render a map into with initial market. I currently have the view setup to render Los Angeles, CA as the center point with the longitude and latitude. Right now it is not rendering anyhing except for the view with the background I created. I want to render the map and have it interactive. Can anyone help me figure out why it is not rendering anything??

code snippet for component:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'

import MapView from 'react-native-maps';

import { PropertiesContext } from '../../Context/PropertiesContext'

const MainMapsConponents = () => {
  const {cityLat, cityLong} = useContext(PropertiesContext)

  return (
    <View>
      <View>
        <Text>{cityLat} - {cityLong}</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.mapWindow}>
        <MapView 
          scrollEnabled={true}
          zoomEnabled={true}
          zoomTapEnabled={true}
          style={styles.map} 
          initialRegion={{
            latitude: cityLat,
            longitude: cityLong,
            latitudeDelta: 0.5,
            longitudeDelta: 0.5,
          }}
        ></MapView>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mapWindow: {
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
    backgroundColor: 'lightgrey'
  }
})

export default MainMapsConponents
```

Here is a screenshot of what I am seeing:
[image: Screenshot of what is rendering]

Answer (score 1):

You need to set it up properly google maps for android and iOS from [here](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/blob/8620a4cc0b49f2c5fd90c46bd602325e10936e58/docs/installation.md).

Working Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Dimensions, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import MapView, { Callout, Marker } from 'react-native-maps';

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');

const ASPECT_RATIO = width / height;
const LATITUDE = 37.78825;
const LONGITUDE = -122.4324;
const LATITUDE_DELTA = 0.0922;
const LONGITUDE_DELTA = LATITUDE_DELTA * ASPECT_RATIO;
const SPACE = 0.01;

const MapDemo = () => {

    const data = {
        region: {
            latitude: LATITUDE,
            longitude: LONGITUDE,
            latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
            longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
        },
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <MapView
                style={styles.map}
                initialRegion={data}
                scrollEnabled={true}
                zoomEnabled={true}
                zoomTapEnabled={true}
                loadingEnabled
                loadingIndicatorColor="#666666"
                loadingBackgroundColor="#eeeeee">

                <Marker
                    coordinate={{
                        latitude: LATITUDE - SPACE,
                        longitude: LONGITUDE - SPACE,
                    }}
                    centerOffset={{ x: -42, y: -60 }}
                    anchor={{ x: 0.84, y: 1 }}>
                    <Callout>
                        <View>
                            <Text>This is a plain view</Text>
                        </View>
                    </Callout>
                </Marker>
            </MapView>
            <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                <View style={styles.bubble}>
                    <Text>Map with Loading</Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    map: {
        ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    },
    bubble: {
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.7)',
        paddingHorizontal: 18,
        paddingVertical: 12,
        borderRadius: 20,
    },
    buttonContainer: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        marginVertical: 20,
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    },
});

export default MapDemo;
```

[image: Screenshot]